# Two cursors not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have two practice tables Table1 and Table2. After inserting a record in Table1, my trigger is getting fired which will insert records in Table2. I have written 2 cursors in my trigger and they need to work at the same time. Thus when my Trigger is getting executed, only one cursor which is first(C_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS) works and not the second(C2_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS) and if I write the second cursor first then too the cursor which is written first works.

Below is only practice code. Trying to describe the issue in simplest possibly way. In reality my requirement is pretty similar and facing the same cursor issue.

Table1 - has 'ID'  'Name' columns

Table2 - has 'ID'  'PANEL_ID'  'SIMILAR_TO'  'VERSION' columns

```
 CREATE TRIGGER SAMPLE_CURSOR 
 AFTER INSERT ON TABLE1 
 FOR EACH ROW 

 BEGIN

 DECLARE C_PANEL_ID,C_SIMILAR_TO, C_VERSION INT;
 DECLARE C2_PANEL_ID,C2_SIMILAR_TO, C2_VERSION INT;

 DECLARE C_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT PANEL_ID, SIMILAR_TO, VERSION
    FROM PANELS_SIMILARS_VERSION
    WHERE VERSION
    IN (SELECT MAX( VERSION ) 
    FROM PANELS_SIMILARS_VERSION
    WHERE PANEL_ID =5
    OR SIMILAR_TO =5
    );

   DECLARE C2_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT PANEL_ID, SIMILAR_TO, VERSION
    FROM PANELS_SIMILARS_VERSION
    WHERE VERSION
    IN (SELECT MAX( VERSION ) 
    FROM PANELS_SIMILARS_VERSION
    WHERE PANEL_ID =5
    OR SIMILAR_TO =5
    );

    // Cursor 1
OPEN C_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS;

// This insert is happenning and the cursor works as required
INSERT INTO log SELECT now(), "Yes","Inside FIRST cursor"; 

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH C_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS INTO C_PANEL_ID,C_SIMILAR_TO,C_VERSION;

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID,PANEL_ID,SIMILAR_TO, VERSION)
VALUES
(NULL, C_PANEL_ID, C_SIMILAR_TO,C_VERSION);

 END LOOP read_loop;
CLOSE C_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS;

//Cursor 2
OPEN C2_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS;

// Statement not getting fired.
INSERT INTO log SELECT now(), "Yes","Inside SECOND cursor"; 

GET_loop: LOOP
FETCH C2_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS INTO C2_PANEL_ID,C2_SIMILAR_TO,C2_VERSION;

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID,PANEL_ID,SIMILAR_TO, VERSION)
VALUES
(NULL, C2_PANEL_ID, C2_SIMILAR_TO,C2_VERSION);

 END LOOP GET_loop;
CLOSE C2_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS;

END;
```

Even when I swap the cursors then too the first cursor in sequence will open and not the second and also forgot to mention it executes successfully without errors.

Comment: Can you edit to include the full trigger (ie the create statement and all the declarations down to the end statement) please.

Comment: I don't see a handler defined is there one?

Comment: Please find the edits.

Comment: Yes everything necessary to make this trigger work is defined. The problem lies in my cursor code which I am not able to figure it out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a continuation handler defined and you don't have a mechanism for exiting your loops. Try adding the lines terminated with #***** below.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER SAMPLE_CURSOR 
 AFTER INSERT ON TABLE1 
 FOR EACH ROW 

 BEGIN

 DECLARE C_PANEL_ID,C_SIMILAR_TO, C_VERSION INT;
 DECLARE C2_PANEL_ID,C2_SIMILAR_TO, C2_VERSION INT;

 DECLARE C_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT PANEL_ID, SIMILAR_TO, VERSION
    FROM PANELS_SIMILARS_VERSION
    WHERE VERSION
    IN (SELECT MAX( VERSION ) 
    FROM PANELS_SIMILARS_VERSION
    WHERE PANEL_ID =5
    OR SIMILAR_TO =5
    );

   DECLARE C2_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS CURSOR FOR
    SELECT PANEL_ID, SIMILAR_TO, VERSION
    FROM PANELS_SIMILARS_VERSION
    WHERE VERSION
    IN (SELECT MAX( VERSION ) 
    FROM PANELS_SIMILARS_VERSION
    WHERE PANEL_ID =5
    OR SIMILAR_TO =5
    );

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;                                 #*****
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;  #*****

    // Cursor 1
OPEN C_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS;

// This insert is happenning and the cursor works as required
INSERT INTO log SELECT now(), "Yes","Inside FIRST cursor"; 

read_loop: LOOP

if done then leave read_loop; end if;                           #*****

FETCH C_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS INTO C_PANEL_ID,C_SIMILAR_TO,C_VERSION;

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID,PANEL_ID,SIMILAR_TO, VERSION)
VALUES
(NULL, C_PANEL_ID, C_SIMILAR_TO,C_VERSION);

 END LOOP read_loop;
CLOSE C_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS;

//Cursor 2

set done = false;                                                       #*****

OPEN C2_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS;

// Statement not getting fired.
INSERT INTO log SELECT now(), "Yes","Inside SECOND cursor"; 

GET_loop: LOOP

if done then leave get_loop; end if;                          #*****

FETCH C2_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS INTO C2_PANEL_ID,C2_SIMILAR_TO,C2_VERSION;

INSERT INTO TABLE2 (ID,PANEL_ID,SIMILAR_TO, VERSION)
VALUES
(NULL, C2_PANEL_ID, C2_SIMILAR_TO,C2_VERSION);

 END LOOP GET_loop;
CLOSE C2_NEW_VERSION_RECORDS;

END;
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This worked as said. I am relatively new to pl-sql but learned something from this.

Comment: Ah.. If question had been tagged pl-sql I would have given a pl-sql answer rather than mysql...